# android change list of spinner depending on another spinner

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have several spinners on my activity

Is it possible to change the contents of spinner 2 depending on what item was selected on spinner 1

the spinners are as follows

```
          <Spinner
          android:id="@+id/spinner1"
          android:layout_width="0sp"
          android:layout_weight="0.6"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
          android:contentDescription="Fred"
          android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
          android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />


      <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner2"
      android:layout_width="0sp"
      android:layout_weight="0.4"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
      android:contentDescription="Fred"
      android:entries="@array/country_arrays2"
      android:prompt="@string/country_prompt2" />
```

How do I change the entries from country_arrays2 to say country arrays 3 in spinner 2 if say item 3 is selected on spinner 1

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your java activity file you can load a spinner content programmatically:

```
    Spinner miSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById("spinner2");

    ArrayAdapter<String> tiposElementos = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tiposElementos.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        tiposElementos.add("Element" + i);
    }

    miSpinner.setAdapter(tiposElementos);
```

addition, you can control the item selected change:

```
miSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int index, long id) {
        your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
};
```